# nth element in iterator

Tags: php, iterator

When I iterate over a folder structure –

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));
```

– is there a way to get at the nth element in the resulting iterator ( `$it` ) directly, that is **without looping** and *without transforming it into an array first* (e.g. using `iterator_to_array()` )?

Comment: Since the iterator could well be a generator (generally anything that makes up its data as it goes, not iterating an existing data structure in memory)... no.

Comment: @deceze Ah, I see, which is why the code in my question executes so damn fast – it doesn't execute at all, until I attempt to do something with it.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, the code in your question doesn't actually do anything just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Since this seems to be the answer you're looking for, reposting my comment as answer:</sub>

Since the iterator could well be a *generator* (anything that makes up its data as it goes, not just iterating over something in memory): no, you cannot directly jump to a specific "index". You have to iterate the iterator to arrive at the particular piece of data you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a while loop and the `next()` and `valid()` methods. Just use a counter and go to the next element until you hit the desired one. At the end you just have to make sure it is still a valid position.

```
$element = 3;
$elementCount = 0;

$it->rewind();
while($elementCount < $element) {
    $it->next();
    $elementCount++;
}


if($it->valid())
    echo $it->current();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, if that was not clear, but the "directly" in my question means that I don't want to loop, because looping takes time (my iterator is 300000 elements long). I'll edit my question to make that more clear.

Comment: @what Directly no. As it is an iterator it goes through the data and *iterates* over it. So there is no way it can jump anywhere directly.

Comment: Thank you, I think I begin to understand. The iterator only begins to do its job when I try to do something with the result of the iteration. Before that, the result does not yet exist.